# How to represent a prime ideal in TeX like in this picture

Tags: symbols

[image: This character is just like the shape of \mathfrak, but it is not the same.]

This character is just like the shape of `\mathfrak{P}`, but it is not the same.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can get this character with the ``\wp`` command. For next time, there are lots of great tools to find symbols, such as [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: @Vincent -- The shape is the same, but the `\wp` {"Weierstrass p") is lowercase. so the baseline is different.  The position shown in the question matches what was used in Unicode prior to version 3, when it was identified (incorrectly) as "power set".

Comment: So what is the upper one in the recent versions?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Interesting, indeed I did not notice that!

Comment: @user11546831 -- Unfortunately, there isn't any.  What is the source of your example?  In particular, when/where was it published?  Searching at `duckduckgo.com` (*not* Google) for "Weierstrass p" shows the symbol and the Wikipedia entry for "Weierstrass's elliptic function" gives a good history.

Comment: Some authors like that symbol, unfortunately.

Comment: @barbarabeeton much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this uppercase `\wp` exists somewhere, but if not it can certainly be defined from the usual `\wp`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newlength{\wpwidth}
\settowidth{\wpwidth}{$\wp$}
\newcommand{\upperwp}{\raisebox{\depth}{\makebox[\wpwidth]{\rotatebox{10}{$\wp$}}}}
\begin{document}
\( \upperwp = \upperwp' \cap A \)
\end{document}
```